# Why we can without loss of generality assume that $\nabla_{Y_p}X=0$ for all $Y_p\in T_pM$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I know that $\nabla_{Y}X|_p=\nabla_{Y_p}X_{u_p}$ where $u_p$ is a neighborhood around $p$.

> **Q1:** Suppose $p$ is a critical point of $f:M\to \Bbb R$ then why $X_pXf$ depends only on $X_p$? Is that true $X_pYf$ for arbitrary $Y$?

By above conditions

> **Q2:** Why  we can without loss of generality assume that $\nabla_{Y_p}X=0$ for all $Y_p\in T_pM$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your vector fields $Y$ and $Z$ are such that $Y_p=Z_p=V$, then since $p$ is a critical point of $f$, you have

$$V(Zf)-V(Yf)=Y_p(Zf)-Z_p(Yf)=[Y,Z]_pf=df_p([Y,Z]_p)=0.$$

Thus, $X_p(Xf)$ only depends of the value of $X_p$.

Comment: Isn't it true that $[Y,Z]_p=0$? just because of $Y_p=Z_p=V$? Any example.

Comment: $Y=-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y},Z=\frac{\partial}{\partial y},f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Then $Y_{(1,0)}=Z_{(1,0)}$ but $Y_{(1,0)}(Zf)=2$ and $Z_{(1,0)}(Yf)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What about my second question?

Comment: I did not understand the second part: how would you link $X$ and $f$? Or are they non related objects?

Comment: for 2 we just know that $p$ is critical point and nothing. and for further calculations the author claimed (2) from (1).

Comment: Is $p$ a critical point of $f$ or a critical point of $X$ in $2$? If it is one of $f$, then I think that for a non zero $X$ we can always find a $Y_p$ s.t. $\nabla_{Y_p}X\neq 0$ (and it is unrelated with $p$ being a critical point of $f$), while if it is one of $X$, this is what I would take as a definition of a point being critical.